# cannot import name 'merge' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers'

Tags: python, merge, concatenation, lstm

I'm sorry if my knowledge in the concatenation is less I'm new to this.
this is NLP-based training. I have used onehot encoding to preprocess the data.
I need to create two LSTM and use concatenation.

this is my concatenation part.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, merge, Activation

first_lstm = Sequential()
first_lstm.add(Embedding(voc_size,embedding_vector_features,input_length=sent_length))
first_lstm.compile('adam','mse')
first_lstm.add(LSTM(50))

sec_lstm = Sequential()
sec_lstm.add(Embedding(voc_size,embedding_vector_features,input_length=sent_length))
sec_lstm.compile('adam','mse')
sec_lstm.add(LSTM(50))

model = Sequential()
model.add(merge([first_lstm,sec_lstm], mode='concat'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),epochs=2,batch_size=64)
model.summary()
```

I'm getting this error for this

`cannot import name 'merge' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers' (C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\api\_v2\keras\layers\__init__.py)`

as many threads say I tried "Merge" with capital M but the same results.
I don't know whether It is my concatenate error or not.
also, is the way I have to concatenate correct?
any solutions!

Comment: What version of tensorflow do you have?

Comment: @JohnGordon 2.7.0

Comment: Maybe you can check the TensorFlow and Keras version correspondence.